# Ranking activation in a grid with sdk 2.0rc1 and wsapi version 2.0

Tags: sdk, rally

I'm moving from sdk 2.0p5 to 2.0rc1 and can't make ranking work in grids.

```
this.down('#leftSide').add({
        xtype:'rallygrid',
        enableRanking: true,
        model: this._models.TestSet,
        storeConfig:{
            fetch:['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Rank'],
            sorters:[
                {property: 'Rank', direction: 'ASC'}
            ]
        },
        columnCfgs: [
            'FormattedID',
            'Name'
        ]
    });
```

I use enableRanking option to activate drag and drop ranking, and it worked perfectly for 2.0p5, but in 2.0rc1 I see the rallyrankcolumn created but it's empty and the functionality of DND is not enabled, so I can't re-rank anything. 
Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppSDK 2.0rc2 was just released:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/sdk.js

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/

and the drag-n-drop ranking works.

Here is a code fragment where `enableRanking` is set to true:

```
 this.grid = this.add({
       xtype: 'rallygrid',
       model: model,
       enableRanking: true,
       columnCfgs: [
            'FormattedID',
             'Name',
             'Priority'
       ],
       storeConfig: {
             fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Priority'],   
             filters : [filter]
       }
 });
```

When the "nameless" rank column's header is clicked and the grid is sorted by rank, the drag-n-drop icons become available.

[image]